# How to execute a function of R from c#?

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to execute a simple function written in R using C# (Installed R.NET) as under

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using RDotNet;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          

            using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\R-core\R"))
            {
                var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
                string rBinPath = (string)registryKey.GetValue("InstallPath");
                string rVersion = (string)registryKey.GetValue("Current Version");
                rBinPath = System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ? rBinPath + "\\bin\\x64" :
                                                                 rBinPath + "\\bin\\i386";
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",
                                      envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
            }


            using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
            {
                // Initializes settings.
                engine.Initialize();


                var myAddFunc = engine.Evaluate(@"addFunc <- function(a,b) {
                                                                 a+b 
                                                  }").AsFunction();

                var sum = engine.Evaluate("@d <- myAddFunc(10,20))").AsNumeric();

                engine.Evaluate("print(sum)");                

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But getting error at

**var sum = engine.Evaluate("@d <- myAddFunc(10,20))").AsNumeric();**

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in RDotNet.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null.*

[image]

What is the mistake that I am doing ?

Running the program in R-Console works fine

```
> addFunc <- function(a,b) {
+    a+b 
+ }
> d<- addFunc(30,40)
> print(d)
[1] 70
```

Answer (score 0):

typo here? @ should be outside of the string. Also it should not be closed by 2 parenthesises.

```
"@d <- myAddFunc(10,20))"
```

should be

```
@"d <- myAddFunc(10,20)"
```

Comment: Even after doing  var sum = engine.Evaluate(@"d <- myAddFunc(10,20))").AsNumeric();, the same problem persist

Comment: ah another typo, myAddFunc(10,20) should not be closed by 2 close paranthesises

Comment: OK, so after i did  var sum = engine.Evaluate(@"d <- myAddFunc(10,20)").AsNumeric();, now i got a new exception An unhandled exception of type 'RDotNet.ParseException' occurred in RDotNet.dll

Additional information: Error in the application.

Comment: your next line `engine.Evaluate("print(sum)");` should have been `engine.Evaluate("print(d)");` instead.

Comment: But the error is occuring at the ar sum = engine.Evaluate(@... line

Comment: Sorry, I have never touched R before, so I would guess that the `@` is necessary for you to assign the value to the variable `d`. (Just my guess). Or maybe you don't even need to assign the value to `d`, therefore what you need to have is just `"myAddFunc(10,20)"`

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late by more than 2 years for this, have you fixed it?
Anyways, try this

```
using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
                {
                    // Initializes settings.
                    engine.Initialize();


                    var myAddFunc = engine.Evaluate(@"addFunc  <- function(a,b) {
                                                        a+b
                                                      }").AsFunction();

                    var sum = engine.Evaluate(@"addFunc(12,30)").AsNumeric();

                    engine.Evaluate("print(sum)");
                    Console.Write(sum[0].ToString());
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
```

you need to use addFunc instead of myAddFunc at second Evaluate statement (i.e.

```
var sum = engine.Evaluate(@"addFunc(12,30)").AsNumeric();
```

)